# Не могу изменить размер у блока "swiper-slide"

Tags: css, reactjs, swiper

Использую библиотеку swiper js и столкнулся с такой проблемой, что у блока "swiper-slide swiper-slide-visible" откуда-то появляется в element.style:  width:152px;

Но я не прописываю это свойство. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как убрать этот width и как сделать свои размеры у слайдов, мне надо сделать их поменьше. Также хочу отодвинуть стрелки переключения о контента.Если кто-то может помочь, напишите, пожалуйста.
[image: help]

Answer (score 0):

Ищите в стилях самого свайпера этот класс, там должен быть прописан стиль. Или же перебейте стиль свайпера со своим значениям через !important

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]